How can I know arm compiler's glibc version?
By googling, I could download the glibc source by
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git  

Now in our project, we are using arm64 compiler this one.
$ aarch64-none-elf-gcc --version
aarch64-none-elf-gcc (GNU Toolchain for the Arm Architecture 11.2-2022.02 (arm-11.14)) 11.2.1 20220111
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

I have this tool installed in my computer. Then how can I know the glibc version of this arm64 toolchain?  (If I knew, I could debug through glibc why the printf function doesn't lead into our _write function. This used to work the other day, but now I don't see _write being called.. )

The aarch64-none-elf target of this toolchain signifies that it is a bare-metal toolchain, not a Linux one. For the toolchain that is distributed by Arm, it means it uses newlib as a libc, not glibc. For a glibc-based toolchain you want to look for an aarch64-none-linux-gnu target

Thank you , I didn't know that.  But the share/info/gcc.info file says this one :
These '-m' options are defined for GNU/Linux targets:
'-mglibc'
Use the GNU C library.  This is the default except on
'--linux-uclibc', '--linux-musl' and '--linux-android'
targets.
Doesn't this mean glibc is used by default?

and I don't know exactly. Is this compiler using the glibc (or newlib) separately installed in my ubuntu system? dpkg -l | grep libc shows ii  libc-bin                                   2.35-0ubuntu3.8                         amd64        GNU C Library: Binaries.  So maybe glibc 2.35 on my system is used??

I think that gcc.info entry is poorly worded. It concerns "linux" toolchains, which can come in uclibc, musl, android or glibc varieties. aarch64-none-elf is not a linux toolchain at all. From the output of your --version command we see that this is the GNU toolchain distributed by Arm. In particular, it's the 11.2 release package. You can find more info about it from https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads
On that page you can check out the sources and see for yourself that the aarch64-none-elf package is newlib-based
